# C# Wpf Prism DelegateCommand in Usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, prism

I've a `UserControl` which is the content of a `ContentControl`. In the `UserControl` is a `Button`, which `Command` property is bound to my VM. The `DataContext` is set in the `ContentControl`. I got not binding errors.

Unfortunately the command won't execute by clicking on the `Button`. When I write a unclean workaround in code-behind it would work.

Maybe have anyone a idea how to fix it. Thanks!

UserControl XAML:

```
<!-- Button in UserControl -->
<Button Content="PrismCommand" Command="{Binding PrismCmd}" PreviewMouseDown="Button_PreviewMouseDown"/>
```

UserControl code-behind:

```
private void Button_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //this would fire the command
    Button bt = sender as Button;
    t.Command.Execute(null);
}
```

VM:

```
 public DelegateCommand PrismCmd { get; private set; }
 public MainViewModel()
 {
     PrismCmd = new DelegateCommand(PrismTest);
 }

 private void PrismTest()
 {
     MessageBox.Show("Execute");
 }
```

Comment: Maybe post more of your XAML code. Based on what you'v posted its hard to find any thing that would cause the command not to fire.

Comment: I thought the problem would be there. But I've made a HitTest which caused that strange behavior. Fixed it finally. Thanks :D